# Menu Structure with Links failure to update

Tags: menus, permalinks, links

Sorry if this sounds like a newbie question but this is driving me crazy and I can't seem to figure it out.  I want to add a link called "About Me" to my Menu that redirects to another website.  It seems like a basic concept.  I go to Appearance and then Menu Structure and add in a custom link with a title "About Me".  It looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLSK6.jpg

I save the menu and hypothetically it should show up on the Menu as planned.

Here is what happens after I refresh on my blog

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV6oe.jpg

Still does not update correctly -   I can't figure this out, any help would be greatly appreciated.  Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a caching plugin enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually create a specific menu and link it to one position you defined in functions.php? Once you do not link it to a position, WordPress grabs all pages and puts it in a menu.

You should go like this:

1.) You put something this in the *functions.php* of your theme in order to register menues (if you only need one, leave out the line with the 'footer' menu):

`function register_my_menus() {
register_nav_menus(
array(
    'nav' => 'Main',
    'footer' => 'Footer' )
);
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );`

2.) You then determine where this should appear in your template, e.g. header.php, just like this: 
`<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'nav' )); ?>`

3.) Last but not least you create your menu and give it the position needed (i.e. 'Main') in my example.

The menu should then update normally. If you use a ready-made theme you might just have to check for the right position to pick in the menu editing window?

Comment: Any update on this matter?